# Entity Framework as a separate Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The layers of the solution are

1. ) DAL (.EDMX file in it)
2. ) BusinessLogic (DAL is being used in it)
3. ) .Net core WebAPI (Businesslogic is being used in it)

Now when I run the project and execution comes to

```
using (var dbContext = new TelehealthEntities())
{
    //Here exception occurs
    var result = dbContext.SchedulerResourceTimings.ToList();
}
```

It throws an exception

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider' from assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.'

TelehealthEntities.cs

```
public partial class TelehealthEntities
{
    public string _connectionString { get; set; }

    public TelehealthEntities(string connectionString)
    {

        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }
}
```

So what is here is missing?

Comment: Could you add the code of your `TelehealthEntities` class? And one more thing, you added the `.net-core` tag to your question, but you just can't use EDMX files with net core, I guess this is a mistake?

Comment: yes its a mistake

Comment: Web API is in .net core

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have entity framework referenced in your WebAPI project